# Why my client doesn't work?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I started following vogella tutorial for REST in Java link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

But I can not create client, this is my code:

```
package com.vogella.jersey.jaxb.client;

import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

public class TodoTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
    // Get XML
    String xmlResponse = target.path("rest").path("todo").request()
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
    // Get XML for application
    String xmlAppResponse =target.path("rest").path("todo").request()
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);

    // For JSON response also add the Jackson libraries to your webapplication
    // In this case you would also change the client registration to
    // ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig().register(JacksonFeature.class);
    // Get JSON for application
    // System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todo").request()
    // .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));

    System.out.println(xmlResponse);
    System.out.println(xmlAppResponse);
  }

  private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/_com.vogella.jersey.jaxb").build();
  }
}
```

I get this errors

```
For build() - The method build(Object[]) in the type UriBuilder is not applicable for the arguments ()

For accept() - The method accept(String[]) in the type Invocation.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

I tried to do this with accept() -

```
String[] appXML = new String[1];
appXML[0] = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
String xmlAppResponse =(String) target.path("rest").path("todo").request()
    .accept(appXML).get(String.class);
```

and this with build() -

```
.build(null);
```

but I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:990)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:799)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:307)
    at de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.client.TodoTest.main(TodoTest.java:25)
```

error is on build(null);

Comment: It is a url issue. what is the url u hit on the browser..? something like this.?. http://localhost:8080/_com.vogella.jersey.jaxb /path/todo

Comment: http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.jaxb/rest/todo
and i get this response 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

    -<todo>

    <description>This is my first todo</description>

    <summary>This is my first todo</summary>

</todo>

Comment: It seems you have given underscore before com in TodoTest class. So url will be   localhost:8080/_com.vogella.jersey.jaxb/rest/todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am little bit ashamed right now.

As @Kaliappan said it's URI issue, I tried to get this

```
http://localhost:8080/_com.vogella.jersey.jaxb
```

but I had

```
_
```

and now I have this URI

```
http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.jaxb
```

and all is working properly. Thank you very much, you are all awesome!

Answer (score 0):

**There is a type mismatch according the the description you provided**:

1. Type mismatch #1

   ```
   For build() - The method build(Object[]) in the type UriBuilder is not applicable for the arguments ()
   ```

   **This means the method is expected `Object` array, but you are not passing anything.**
2. Type mismatch #2

   ```
   For accept() - The method accept(String[]) in the type Invocation.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (String)
   ```

   **This means the method is expected `String` array, but you are passing simple `String`.**

Comment: yeah, but for build() i do not need anything, no value at all, so i passed null, and for accept() i passed appXML array that contains only one String i need, and i get NotFoundException

And thank you so much for responding!!!